# MVC Routes: Adding an optional parameter at the beginning of a route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following routes setup in my route config file. I have a config reader that maps these to MVC-style routes.

`[route name="customers" url="customers/{statename}/{marketname}/{pagenumber}"]
      [controller name="Customers" action="Display" /]
    [/route]`

```
[route name="pcustomers" url="{customername}/customers/{statename}/{marketname}/{pagenumber}"]
  [controller name="Customers" action="Display" /]
[/route]
```

As you can tell, the first and second route are pretty much the same but for the {customername} part in the second one.

The first one matches urls like
**www.abc.com/customers/TX/Austin/5**

where as the second one matches urls like
**www.abc.com/CustomerX/customers/TX/Austin/5**

My question is, is there a way to combine these two routes into one and still be able to match both the urls?

Answer (score 2):

Could you use subdomains and change the second URL to customerx.abc.com/customers/tx/Austin/5?  What about tacking the customerx potion onto the end as an optional parameter like so?
abc.com/customers/tx/Austin/5?customer=x

Comment: That was one of the ideas that had crossed my mind. Alas, I can't do it that way though. We have an existing site that uses Webforms and all the urls are in production already. We are migrating this app in a piecemeal fashion to MVC. So, it's essential that we maintain the same url scheme :(

Comment: In that case maybe redirecting permanently as described here would be a solution (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would've made the route like this:

```
customers/{statename}/{marketname}/{customer}
```

and do the pagenumber as a querystring.
That way the url would be:

```
www.abc.com/customers/tx/Austin?pagenumber=1
```

or

```
www.abc.com/customers/tx/Austin/CustomerX
```

The construction of the url will also most likely follow the usagepattern of the site aswell:

1. Click Customers
2. Select a State
3. Select a marketname
4. Browse pages
5. Click the customer

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot go with a different URL scheme. We have to stick to our existing scheme for backward-compatibility as well as SEO.

Comment: @Praveen - you have probably solved this, but why can't you do 301 redirects to the new URL scheme?